# Generation of codes with n different characters

Tags: combinatorics, coding-theory

I am generating codes with the following properties:

- `A`: number of different values to compose the codes from (the alphabet size)
- `L`: length each code
- `D`: each code must differ on at least D indices from each other code.

I want to find the maximum set of codes, and generate them efficiently if possible.

- When `D = 1`: this is trivial iteration.
- When `D = 2`: I came up with the following: 
  Store the code in base-`A`, and add `A+1` until you overflow, starting from `0`. This is however slightly suboptimal.
- When `D = 3`: I have no clue...

Does anyone know a way to find the maximum set of codes for `D = 2`, `D = 3`, or generalized for any `D`?

---

Counterexample showing my method for `D = 2` is not optimal:

`A = 3`
`L = 3`
`D = 2`

My method (7 codes):

`000 011 022 110 121 202 220`

Better witness (8 codes):

`002 010 021 100 111 122 201 220`

Comment: you might want to add coding theory tag by editing

Comment: With $A=L=3$, $D=2$ you easily get a code with nine words: $000$ ,$111$, $222$, $012$, $120$, $201$, $021$, $102$, $210$. This set has the property that the sum of the components has remainder $0$ modulo $3$. It is easy to see why such a condition forces any pair of words to differ in at least two positions. This is also easily seen to be an optimal construction as any set with more than two words necessarily has at least one pair sharing the same first two letters. In general this is an open question, and several books and thousands of scientific articles have been written on the theme.